# Aluminium PCB - Bottom Entry Connector

Tags: pcb, connector, surface-mount, lighting, aluminium

Is there something like this connector that is easier to buy? I need to find something that lets me connect an aluminium PCB to an FR4 PCB with part of the enclosure between them. The part of this connector that sticks into the PCB is spaced from the SMD legs enough to not have to worry about shorting any of the pins on the aluminium core.
https://www.ghgmlink.com/g15-m2012-double-row-right-angle-dip-led-light-connector-straight-style-intelligent-lighting-connector-pitch-2-0mm-2-6-pin-female-mating-connector_p42.html

Connectors like this a commonly found in downlights and allow you to pass pins through the connector on each PCB.

[image]

Image Source: Photos I took myself.

Comment: They're easy enough to buy in China, where most lamp manufacturing is done.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Spehro. Do you have a link? I've still not been able to find them.

Comment: Try one of the domestic sites such as tmall. You'll have to search in hanzi, though.

Answer (score 0):

For example Samtec BCS is a pass-through pin socket:
https://www.samtec.com/products/bcs

The pin header just needs to be long enough to extend far enough to the other side of the PCB.

Comment: Thanks Ralph. Through hole connectors like that are very difficult to use with aluminium PCBs. And although Samtech and other brands have SMD equivalents, the aluminium wouldn't be "spaced from the SMD legs enough to not have to worry about shorting any of the pins to the aluminium core."

Comment: If it's just a protective element, could you use for example a panel mounted LED holder?

Comment: > I'm asking if there is something similar that's easier to purchase, hoping for a vendor like DigiKey or Mouser. -- No, there aren't. These particular ones are only made and sold by Chinese sources.

Comment: Thanks Ralph. I think you could do that for a larger pitch and with long enough legs to bend back to a pad. Might be difficulty with a connector like this though. Maybe a 2L adaptor PCB could add the clearance I'm after to the connector you suggested.